# Send a JSON array within an URL

Tags: arrays, url

I am using Runscope to test my Node/Express app and I can't figure out how to send a array in an URL via a DELETE request in Runscope.

I need to send a JSON array with UUIDs of handled messages within the URL.

Comment: Can you make a failing result shareable and email the link to help@runscope.com? We'll gladly take a look.